# How to include a SSL certificate in the rest call

Tags: java, rest, grails, ssl, https

Hi i am new to security domain. So please let me know if i am missing something very obvious.

I am trying to create an application that runs on https and requires a SSL certificate.
i followed the [this blog](http://ekiras.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-and-add-certificate-to-keystore.html) to create a ssl certificate and add it to the java security cacerts.

Now i want to create a https post request to this application. The request fails every time. What i found till now is

1. The certificate is not verified, thats why it is not authorizing the rest call to proceed.
2. When i open the application in browser, it asks me to confirm the certificate, once i accept it, all rest calls start working.

Can any one tell me what can i do to avoid this(confirming the certificate.)
1. Can i bypass the ssl certificate check ?
2. Can i add certificate to every rest call.
3. Anything else that i should try.
4. I saw looking at [this grails plugin](https://github.com/USF-IT/CAS-REST-clients/tree/master/Grails/cas-rest-client), how do i create a .jks file ?

Ay help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't bypass the certificate check on the clients' side. A very important point of having a certificate at all is for it to be signed by a trusted authority. If you have signed it yourself, you can still have an encrypted connection, but the clients can't know you're verified by a trusted third party.
2. You can configure the application or web server to use the keystore that your certificate is in in order to attach it to every https request. Look up tomcat ssl configuration.
3. I would advise that you read up a bit more on https and certificates, it's important to understand some details.
4. It's preferable that you delegate the ssl management to the application server instead of doing that in your rest calls yourself. See 2. Also, a .jks is just a keystore file. You already have one from the tutorial you've followed.

Comment: In particular and without question, number 4. Don't do ssl yourself :)